# R loading function from same file

Tags: r

I am trying to run the following R script:

```
#########################################################################
#####################     SUPPLEMENTARY METHODS     #####################
#########     Implementation of NtAI, LST and HRD-LOH in R     ##########
#########################################################################


#########################################################################
############################     HOW TO USE    ##########################
#########################################################################

# 'x' is a matrix of segmented output from ASCAT, with at least the
#   following columns (column names are not important):
# 1: sample id
# 2: chromosome (numeric)
# 3: segment start
# 4: segment end
# 5: number of probes
# 6: total copy number
# 7: nA
# 8: nB
# 9: ploidy
# 10: contamination, aberrant cell fraction

chrominfo <- GetChrominfo() # hg19


GetChrominfo <- function() {
  # Get chromInfo table from UCSC
  chrom <- GetGzFromUrl("http://hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/hg19/database/chromInfo.txt.gz", header = FALSE)
  chrom <- subset(chrom, grepl("^chr[0-9XY]{1,2}$", chrom[,1]))
  # Get gap table from UCSC
  gaps <- GetGzFromUrl("http://hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/hg19/database/gap.txt.gz", header = FALSE)
  centro <- subset(gaps, gaps[,8] == "centromere")
  # Merge the relevant info from the two tables
  chrominfo <- merge(chrom[,1:2], centro[,2:4], by.x = 1, by.y = 1) # merge size and centromere location
  chrominfo$centromere <- rowMeans(chrominfo[,3:4]) # convert centromere start and end into one location (the mean)
  chrominfo <- chrominfo[,c(1,2,5,3,4)] # keep chromosome, size and centromere location
  colnames(chrominfo) <- c("chr", "size", "centromere", "centstart", "centend")
  chrominfo[,1] <- as.character(chrominfo[,1])
  chrominfo$chr <- sub("chr", "", chrominfo$chr)
  chrominfo$chr <- sub("X", "23", chrominfo$chr)
  chrominfo$chr <- sub("Y", "24", chrominfo$chr)
  chrominfo[,1] <- as.numeric(chrominfo[,1])
  chrominfo <- chrominfo[order(chrominfo$chr), ]  # order by chromosome number
  rownames(chrominfo) <- as.character(chrominfo[,1])
  chrominfo <- as.matrix(chrominfo)
  return(chrominfo)  
}
```

I tried running it both in RStudio and through the `Rscript` command. However, I keep getting this error: `Error in GetChrominfo() : could not find function "GetChrominfo"`. I'm not sure why, as `GetChrominfo` is clearly defined in the same file. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: don't you need to move the call to after the definition of GetChrominfo()?

Comment: Oh ok. I'll try that; sorry, new to R.